# Maple: How having assumptions for variables to be from real range to solve such equasion?

Tags: maple

So I have an equation like this:

[image: Im(G[x,x]) = -38/(845*Pi)+ Re(G[x,y])]

I need to get `G[xy]`. How to tell Maple that we are assuming that `G[xx]`, `G[xy]` are values from real range (So `Im(G[xx]) == 0` and `Re(G[xy]) == G[xy]`) and find `G[xy]` from `Im(solution[1][1])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `assume` or `assuming`. In your case:

```
solve(Im(G[x,x]) = -38/(845*Pi) + Re(G[x,y]), G[x,y]) assuming G[x,y] :: real, G[x,x] :: real;
```

would work.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to not use `assuming` for this kind of thing, as it gives the potentially misleading impression that `solve` is robust with respect to handling and working with assumptions.

By using `evalc` to preprocess the system. it's a little easier to keep in mind just what `solve` is handling.

```
solve( evalc(Im(G[x,x]) = -38/(845*Pi) + Re(G[x,y])), G[x,y] );

                           38  
                         ------
                         845 Pi

evalc(Im(G[x,x]) = -38/(845*Pi) + Re(G[x,y]));

                         38            
                 0 = - ------ + G[x, y]
                       845 Pi
```

It's a personal preference, and you may well come up with reasons to prefer going the other route, as a rule. Or perhaps sometimes both methods will find their niche.